# How to keep yaml Format when using yaml.SafeDumper

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML file

```
Version: "1.0"
title1: "Title 1"
title2: [Title 2]
```

I open the file using

```
def open_file(input_file):
    with open(input_file, encoding="utf8") as file:
        return_file = yaml.safe_load(file)
        return return_file
```

in runtime it looks like this:

```
{'Version': '1.0', 'title1': 'Title 1', 'title2': ['Title 2']}
```

the output I receive is:

```
Version: "1.0"
title1: Title 1
title2:
- Title 2
```

How do i keep the original formatting for "title1" and "title2" ?

I write the file as such:

```
    with open(output_file_name, "w", encoding="utf8") as dump_file:
        yaml.dump(<runtime_file>, dump_file, Dumper=MyDumper, sort_keys=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

with

```
class MyDumper(yaml.SafeDumper):
    def write_line_break(self, data=None):
        super().write_line_break(data)
        if len(self.indents) == 1:
            super().write_line_break()
        if len(self.indents) == 2:
            super().write_line_break()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using PyYAML and that supports only (a subset of) YAML 1.1, whereas YAML 1.2 was released more than thirteen
years ago. You should upgrade to `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author) that has been developed since 2014
to specifically preserve orginal layout, quotes, comments, anchors/aliases, number formats, etc.

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from pathlib import Path

file_in = Path('input.yaml')
file_out = Path('output.yaml')
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2) 
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(file_in)
yaml.dump(data, file_out)

print(file_out.read_text())
```

which gives:

```
Version: "1.0"
title1: "Title 1"
title2: [Title 2]
```

Since some of your scalar strings are superfluously quoted and others are not, you
cannot easily achieve this in PyYAML. You would have to load the quoted strings into
a different class than the non-quoted ones, so that they dump back as their originals.
Depending on what you need to do with those loaded data, you need to make those classes behave
mostly like a normal string. For that you need to dig into the PyYAML internals. `ruamel.yaml` takes
care of all of that for you (in its default round-trip mode).

Comment: Thanks, This works for the format.
It seems to have trouble with russian and chinese characters.

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: character maps to <undefined>

with PYYAML i can specify encoding="utf8" to solva tahat problem. with ruamel.yaml utf-8 seems to be the default.

any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Do you use a `pathlib.Path` instance or do you open the file yourself. Are you on Windows?. It could be that the file has a BOM that is not properly handled. You can also read in the file into a variable `yaml_str` and then call `yaml.load(yaml_str)` (but it would be good to know what is going wrong so post a question with a dump of the first lines of the file (to show hidden characters), your code and your platform.

Comment: I work on windows, I use `file_in = Path('input.yaml')` and` file_out = Path('output.yaml')` for the files.

Importing the file works. The error occurs while executing `yaml.dump(data, file_out)`.
The output File gets created fine until Chinese or Russian characters are includet.

Comment: @Marc I thought this was during reading, I currently cannot test under windows,  can you try to do: `with open('output.yaml', 'wb') as fp:` followed by `    yaml.dump(data, fp)`?